# Calculating product by addition

Tags: algorithm, haskell

This is an algorithm question that I've been struggling with. I figured I could get some insight here. I need to make the following function in Haskell:

> Declare the type and define a function that takes two numbers as input and finds their product by addition. That is, add the first number, as many times as second number, to itself.

My problem is that this is basically just multiplying two numbers together, but it says that I need to do it with addition. Does anyone have any clue on how to do this?

This is all I can come up with (it's not right): `(x + x) * y`

Thank you

Comment: add the first number, as many times as second number, to itself.

Comment: Correct, but algorithm wise...

Comment: What I cited is an algorithm that can be translated into code almost literally. At what point do you have difficulties doing that?

Comment: It's actually not quite the same as multiplication; the function described is not commutative, i.e. `f (-2) 3` won't equal `f 3 (-2)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
mult (x, y):
  sum = 0
  for 1 to y:
    sum = sum + x
  return sum
```

This is just the algorithm. I do not know Haskell. So the lambda expression in the other answer may be more appropriate. Also, I use an intermediate variable.

PS: forget the previous embarrassing recursive algorithm

Comment: Is `mult` defined by you or is it a default function?

Comment: This is just the pseudocode of the algorithm. You can see I have defined `mult` and calling it recursively till `y` exhausts. I suggest you to pick CLRS.

Comment: So basically `mult` is loaded in from a .hs file? Is it possible to complete the function entirely in a preloaded file?

Comment: This pseudocode computes something like `2^y*x` instead of `y*x`, doesn't it?

Comment: There are no loops in Haskell, so your pseudocode is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

if `a` is the first number and `b` the second

```
sum $ take a $ cycle [b]
```

should do ot

Comment: Or simply `replicate a b` :)

Comment: What are the `$` signs for?

Comment: I do not. Is it a search engine for symbols?

Comment: @Eric: Did you click on the link, examine its contents and find your way to the homepage of the site that explains what the site is and does?

Answer (score 2):

Work it out by induction.

We know the answer to one simple (the simplest) problem: multiplying anything by 0 yields 0. So we write:

```
mul x 0 = 0
```

Now, the inductive step: we can build a solution to a bigger problem, if we know a solution to the smaller problem; that way we can always reduce any big problem to the smallest problem, for which we know the solution. So, for any `y`, the solution for y+1 can be found by adding x to the solution for y: `mul x (y+1) = x + (mul x y)`. In Haskell we can't write (y+1) on the left hand side, so we write equivalently:

```
mul x y = x + (mul x (y-1))
```

This function will keep adding `x` until `y` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this also

```
multiply::(Num a,Eq a) => a -> a -> a
multiply a 0 = 0
multiply a b = a + multiply a (b - 1)

main = print $ multiply 5 7
```